# Count new items tried each day without including those tried on previous days - Using PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

How to get count of **new unique items** tried each day (this shouldn't include items that were already tried previously) - **Using PostgreSQL**

**Input:**

| Date | Order-ID | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-04-21 | 1 | Apple |
| 05-04-21 | 2 | Orange |
| 05-04-21 | 3 | Apple |
| 06-04-21 | 4 | Apple |
| 06-04-21 | 5 | Banana |
| 06-04-21 | 6 | Orange |
| 07-04-21 | 7 | Apple |
| 07-04-21 | 8 | Banana |
| 07-04-21 | 9 | Orange |

**Desired Output:**

| Date | New Items |
| --- | --- |
| 05-04-21 | 2 |
| 06-04-21 | 1 |
| 07-04-21 | 0 |

On 06-04-21, 1 new item was tried - counts only Banana since Apple & Orange were tried previously on 05-04-21 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to achieve what you looking for. The following walks through each of those steps. Some steps could possible be combined, but not here. This will not necessarily be the shortest query available. But the goal is not to produce the shortest query, but to show the a think process and working in sets.

1. Eliminate any duplicate items for a single day. ( reduce Apple on
   05/24 to 1).
2. Eliminate any item from a date where that item occurs is a prior
   date.
3. Count the number of items remaining for each date.
4. From the original data get each day testing was done.
5. For each date in #4 get the number of items remaining from #3, if
   none show 0.
6. Order the final result.

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d7ef5ee307192c865ca8d1321dffc7e5)

```
with items (ord_date, order_id, item) as                               -- 0 Define test data instead of actual table
     ( values (date '2021-05-04', 1, 'Apple')
            , (date '2021-05-04', 2, 'Orange')
            , (date '2021-05-04', 3, 'Apple')
            , (date '2021-06-04', 4, 'Apple')
            , (date '2021-06-04', 5, 'Banana')
            , (date '2021-06-04', 6, 'Orange')
            , (date '2021-07-04', 7, 'Apple')
            , (date '2021-07-04', 8, 'Banana')
            , (date '2021-07-04', 9, 'Orange')
      ) 
      
-- your query starts here 
-- get date and number of items remaining
select idt.ord_date "date", coalesce(s2.cnt,0) "items"                           -- 5
  from ( get each date having orders/items                                       -- 4
        select distinct ord_date  
          from items   
       ) idt
  left join (-- for each date count the number of items                 
             select ord_date, count(*) cnt                                       -- 3  
               from (-- reduce th just 1 row per item per day
                     select distinct on (ord_date, item)                         -- 1 
                            ord_date, item
                       from items 
                      order by ord_date, item
                    )  s
              where not exists ( -- elminate items with checked on a prior day   -- 2
                                 select null 
                                   from items i 
                                  where i.item = s.item
                                    and i.ord_date < s.ord_date
                               )
              group by s.ord_date
            ) s2
         on ( s2.ord_date = idt.ord_date) 
order by idt.ord_date;                                                            -- 6 final ordering
```